# Get original RANK() value based on row create date

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Using MariaDB and trying to see if I can get pull original rankings for each row of a table based on the create date.

For example, imagine a scores table that has different scores for different users and categories (lower score is better in this case)

| id | leaderboardId | userId | score | submittedAt ↓ | rankAtSubmit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 15 | 555 | 50.5 | 2022-01-20 01:00:00 | 2 |
| 8 | 15 | 999 | 58.0 | 2022-01-19 01:00:00 | 3 |
| 7 | 15 | 999 | 59.1 | 2022-01-15 01:00:00 | 3 |
| 6 | 15 | 123 | 49.0 | 2022-01-12 01:00:00 | 1 |
| 5 | 15 | 222 | 51.0 | 2022-01-10 01:00:00 | 1 |
| 4 | 14 | 222 | 87.0 | 2022-01-09 01:00:00 | 1 |
| 5 | 15 | 555 | 51.0 | 2022-01-04 01:00:00 | 1 |

The "rankAtSubmit" column is what I'm trying to generate here if possible.

**I want to take the best/smallest score of each user+leaderboard and determine what the rank of that score was when it was submitted.**

My attempt at this failed because in MySQL you cannot reference outer level columns more than 1 level deep in a subquery resulting in an error trying to reference `t.submittedAt` in the following query:

```
SELECT *, (
        SELECT ranking FROM (
            SELECT id, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY leaderboardId ORDER BY score ASC) ranking
            FROM scores x
            WHERE x.submittedAt <= t.submittedAt
            GROUP BY userId, leaderboardId
        ) ranks
        WHERE ranks.id = t.id
    ) rankAtSubmit
FROM scores t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `RANK()`, I was able to accomplish this by with a single subquery that counts the number of users that have a score that is lower than and submitted before the given score.

```sql
SELECT id, userId, score, leaderboardId, submittedAt,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userId) + 1
    FROM scores t2
    WHERE t2.userId = t.userId AND
          t2.leaderboardId = t.leaderboardId AND
          t2.score < t.score AND
          t2.submittedAt <= t.submittedAt
  ) AS rankAtSubmit
FROM scores t
```

Answer (score -1):

What I understand from your question is you want to know the minimum and maximum rank of each user.
Here is the code

```
SELECT  userId, leaderboardId, score, min(rankAtSubmit),max(rankAtSubmit)
FROM scores 
group BY userId,
     leaderboardId,
     scorescode here
```

Comment: You’ve misunderstood the question.